# How to serialise (pretty print) spray JsValue to an java Writer

Tags: scala, spray

I'd like to be able to serialise (i.e. pretty print) a rather large spray JsValue to e.g. a java.io.BufferedWriter **without** having to first generate an intermediate string.

This seems like it should be a fairly straightforward thing, but spray's JsonPrinter is based on a StringBuilder.

So, does spray and/or standard libraries support this?  Or did someone write an appropriate adapter to be able to 'stream write' a JsValue to a java.io.Writer (or OutputStream)?

Comment: by writing a custom `JsValue` to `ByteStream`. how else ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like (untested):

```
import java.io.PrintWriter
import spray.json._

def streamOut(js: JsValue, out: PrintWriter): Unit = {
  js match {
    case JsObject(elems) =>
      out.print("{")
      for {
        ((k, v), i) <- elems.zipWithIndex
      } {
        val comma = if (i == 0) "" else "," 
        out.print(s"$comma$k:")
        streamOut(v, out)
      }
      out.print("}")
    case JsArray(elems) =>
      out.print("[")
      for {
        (v, i) <- elems.zipWithIndex
      } {
        val comma = if (i == 0) "" else ","
        out.print(comma)
        streamOut(v, out)
      }
      out.print("]")
    case _ => out.print(js.compactPrint)
  }
}
```